# Passing a pointer to structure type in a function

Tags: c, struct, typedef

This might be a pretty basic question but I am a newbie in C so please bear with me.

I am going through some documentation for a firmware written in C where I came across this:

```
typedef struct {
                 int x;
                 int arr[10];
               } sx;
```

Then I have a function where a pointer to that type is being passed.

```
int f(sx xtype *sp, int i){
                            return sp -> arr[i];
                          }
```

I am not sure where about two things:
From my Java experience I think the first snippet is equivalent to a superclass much like Object class in Java and then the second snippet is using a subclass of sx. However I am not sure. Can anyone please confirm?
From my little C experience so far, I think more easy-to-understand way to pass a pointer to the type would be as follows:

```
typedef struct xtype {
                 int x;
                 int arr[10];
                 } sx;

int f(sx *sp, int i){
                     return sp -> arr[i];
                    }
```

But I just suspect I am missing something from this picture. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find the definition of `xtype`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unusual syntax. I suspect that `xtype` is a macro defined somewhere and *could* look something like this

```
#define xtype const
```

At any rate, the declaration of a variable `sx xtype *sp` does *not* say that `sp` refers to a subtype `xtype` of `sx` or this is the worst pre-processor magic I've seen in a long time.

---

As for your second example, this doesn't model sub-classing, either. What this:

```
typedef struct A {
  /* ... */
} B;
```

says is that `struct A` is the same as `B`. It's a `typedef`: It just defines a new type, a short rephrased version of the longer name.

```
void func(struct A);
void func(B); // exactly equivalent
```

It has *nothing* to do with inheritance.